# How to get specific string in two subtring in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

Here is the example:

`review: I love you very much... reviewer:jackson review: I hate you very much... reviewer:madden review: sky is pink and i ... reviewer: tom`

i want extract the string between string `review:` and `...`

So above situation's extraction is

`I love you very much`

`I hate you very much`

`sky is pink and i`

i use this kind of regex but fail

`re.findall("review(.*)...",string)`

it extract this kind of outcome:

`I love you very much... reviewer:jackson review: I hate you very much... reviewer:madden review: sky is pink and i`

Answer (score 2):

this will also work and it's simple

```
str = "review: I love you very much... reviewer:jackson review: I hate you very much... reviewer:madden review: sky is pink and i ... reviewer: tom"

matches = re.findall('review:(.+?)\.\.\.', str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` with the pattern `\breview:\s*(.*?)\.\.\.\s*(?=\breviewer:|$)`:

```
inp = "review: I love you very much... reviewer:jackson review: I hate you very much... reviewer:madden review: sky is pink and i ... reviewer: tom"
matches = re.findall(r'\breview:\s*(.*?)\.\.\.\s*(?=\breviewer:|$)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['I love you very much', 'I hate you very much', 'sky is pink and i ']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following pattern which utilizes lookaheads:

```
(?<=review:\s).*?(?=\.\.\.)
```

---

```
inp = "review: I love you very much... reviewer:jackson review: I hate you very much... reviewer:madden review: sky is pink and i ... reviewer: tom"
matches = re.findall(r'(?<=review:\s).*?(?=\.\.\.)', inp)
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
re.findall(r'\breview:\s*(.*?)\s*\.\.\.', string)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/TmSXkU/1/). [Python test](https://tio.run/##fY/NDoIwEITvPMWkJyCmF28kxrPvwKXSFSr0J21BefpaxYR4MXPYZOebZMatcbDmmJLSzvoIT4Wnnp44wbP26mlR9GjaUJe8Plf5tvwtVoTolekzxr4MLpjsQljtjIX8Cj13A@ccm0@@uYtuDNZgDwwi/gtoISXtfBhXqACnzAhhJBR@aESrWeFyrYgyv/lNGSmmqfwMOmBrXKFK6QU):

```
import re
regex = r"\breview:\s*(.*?)\s*\.\.\."
string = "review: I love you very much... reviewer:jackson review: I hate you very much... reviewer:madden review: sky is pink and i ... reviewer: tom"
print ( re.findall(regex, string) )
```

Output: `['I love you very much', 'I hate you very much', 'sky is pink and i']`

Note the `r"..."` prefix signalling raw string literal since `"\b"` is not a word boundary, and `r"\b"` is.

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  review:                  'review:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.\.\.                   '...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry
i forget to add `\` in front of  `.`

and the right one is:
`re.findall("review:\b?(.*)\.\.\.",string)`

and this time , it counts

Comment: This will not work. You want a non-greedy match. Please have a look at `?` in the capture in my answer.

Comment: Also, please look at my answer `:-)`

Comment: Good, great help!